# Doctrine ODM query by subfield of reference-one

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have an existing MongoDb database:

```json
Foo
{
  "_id": ObjectId(123456789),
  "name": "foo_1",
  "barId": 123,
  "sellerId": 456
}

Bar
{
  "_id": "123",
  "ref": "A1",
  "status": "paid"
}
```

Here is my mapping:

```xml
<document name="Foo">
   <id />
   <field field-name="name" type="string" />
   <field field-name="status" type="string" />
   <reference-one target-document="Bar" field="barId" store-as="id"/>
</document>
   
<document name="Bar">
   <id strategy="NONE" type="string" />
   <field field-name="ref" type="string" />
   <field field-name="status" type="string" />
</document>
```

I want to query all Foo filtered by `sellerId` and `Bar.status = "paid"`

But I can only filter by `Bar id` and no other fields. How can I do that?

```php
//FooRepository.php

public function getAll(string $sellerId)
{
     $query = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                   ->field('sellerId')->equals($sellerId) // ok
    //             ->field('barId.status')->equals('paid') // ko
                   ->field('barId')->equals('123') // ok
            ;
    
     $query->readOnly();

     return $this->paginate($query);
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your logical query? what do you want to get exactly?

Comment: I want to get a list of Foo where their associated Bar has status "paid" (but I can only filter where Bar.id = "", not Bar.status="")

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB's querying does not support "joins" like relational databases do. The closest thing to a `LEFT JOIN` is aggregation pipeline's [$lookup](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). Please refer to ODM's [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/2.3/reference/aggregation-builder.html#lookup) on how to use aggregation builder and its stages with the library.